# How to fill a rectangle with some color along with printing a string in Processing console?

Tags: processing

I'm developing a GUI for Arduino mega 2560 using Processing (control p5 library).
My board senses analog pin A0 and continuously displays its value as string in console. If a specific digital pin goes high then It sends the error string to processing console and waits for reset to be pressed.

> Ex: A1-B1 error press reset

If A1-B1 is error then I want my GUI to fill the rectangle with red along with displaying string

> " A1-B1 error press reset"

How to I do this?

Here's my processing code

```java
   import java.util.*;
    import at.mukprojects.console.*;
    Console console;
    import processing.serial.*;
     Serial port;
     import controlP5.*;
     ControlP5 cp5;
     int myColorBackground = color(0, 0, 0);
       float k,l;
      String val;
       int i;
          char a;
    void setup() {
      size(800,600);
      frame.setResizable(true);
         smooth();
      noStroke();
         printArray(Serial.list());
         port = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[0],9600);
     port.bufferUntil(10);
      cp5 = new ControlP5(this); //init gui lib
      console = new Console(this); //init console
     console.start(); 
    }
void draw() {
  background(myColorBackground);
  fill(250, 131, 3); //text color
   console.draw();
   k= (width*0.75);
 l=(0.25*height)-50;
    fill(0);
  stroke(250, 131, 1);
  rect(k+20, l+20, 12,12);
  fill(250, 131, 3);
  textFont(font, 16);
  text("A1-B1", k+100, l+20);
      }
     void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
  while(port.available()>0){
    val = port.readStringUntil(10);
      }
 if (val!=null)
 {

println(val);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your code will be much easier to read if you fix your indentation. Or better yet, post a [mcve] instead of your full program.

Comment: @Kevin Workman  : i'll edit and change it to a minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice we can give you is to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those pieces on one at a time.

For example, can you create a simple sketch that displays a message after the mouse has been clicked? Forget about the Arduino for a minute and just get this working by itself. It might look something like this:

```
boolean mouseWasPressed = false;

void draw(){
  if(mouseWasPressed){
    background(255, 0 , 0);
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  mouseWasPressed = true;
}
```

Separately from that, get a sketch working that just shows the Arduino message in the console. It sounds like you might already have a lot of that done, but try to isolate it in a small example program.

When you have both of those working separately, then you can start thinking about combining them into one program. And if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly which step you're stuck on. Good luck.

Comment: I've already worked on arduino program. when fault is detected arduino sends text to console in processing shown in question. but additionally i also want rectangle to be filled with red along with text.